# Jquery ui datepicker instead of selectfield in grails scafolding

Tags: grails

In grails scafolding,normally there are 3 or 4 select fields for entering date. Can we change 'renderEditor.template' in such a manner that we can use  jquery ui datepicker instead.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230852/how-to-override-standard-behavior-of-applicationtaglibcreatelink-and-glink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

successfully integrated jquery UI datepicker inside grails template

Replace 'renderDateEditor' in renderEditor.template with the following code:

```
   private renderDateEditor(domainClass, property) {
    def precision = (property.type == Date || property.type == java.sql.Date ||    property.type == Calendar) ? "day" : "minute";
    if (!cp) {
        return "<g:datePicker name=\"${property.name}\" precision=\"${precision}\" value=\"\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}}\" />"
    } else {
        if (!cp.editable) {
            return "\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}?.toString()}"
        } else {
            def out = new StringBuffer("")

            out << "<input type=\"text\" name=\"${property.name}_datepicker\" id=\"${property.name}_datepicker\" value=\"<g:formatDate date=\"\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}}\" formatName=\"dateonly.date.format\" />\"/>"
            out << "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${property.name}_day\" id=\"${property.name}_day\" value=\"<g:formatDate date=\"\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}}\" format=\"dd\" />\"/>"
            out << "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${property.name}_month\" id=\"${property.name}_month\" value=\"<g:formatDate date=\"\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}}\" format=\"MM\" />\"/>"
            out << "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${property.name}_year\" id=\"${property.name}_year\" value=\"<g:formatDate date=\"\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}}\" format=\"yyyy\" />\"/>"
            out << """<g:javascript>
                          \$(document).ready(function () {
                              \$("#${property.name}_datepicker").datepicker({
                                  dateFormat:'dd/MM/yy',
                                  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                                          var date = new Date(dateText.replace(/(\\d+).(\\d+).(\\d+)/, '\$3/\$2/\$1'));
                                          if (!isNaN(date)) {
                                              \$("#${property.name}_month").val(date.getMonth()+1);
                                              \$("#${property.name}_day").val(date.getDate());
                                              \$("#${property.name}_year").val(date.getFullYear());
                                          }
                                        },
                                  showAnim: "slide",
                                  showOptions: {direction: 'up'},
                                  showOn: "both",
                                  autoSize: true,
                                  constrainInput: true,
                                  showButtonPanel: true
                              });
                          })
                      </g:javascript>"""
            return out.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

by doing this we can replace default date selector ui of grails with jQuery ui datepicker

Answer (score 0):

One way for doing it is on the JavaScript layer as a progressive enhancement.

It has an advantage of keeping the templates untouched.

This could be done by adding a jquery live hook on grails datepicker generated DOM.

Heres is what i came up with in a project :

```
        $("input[type=hidden][value='date.struct']" ).live(function(evt){
            var dateSelect = $(this).next();
            var monthSelect = dateSelect.next();
            var yearSelect = monthSelect.next();
            yearSelect.after("<button>Calendar</button>").next().button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-calendar"
                },
                text: false
            }).on('click',function(evt){
            var comp = $(this);
            comp.datepicker( "dialog",null,function(dateText, inst) {

                var dateArray = dateText.split("/");

                monthSelect.val(parseInt(dateArray[0]).toString());
                dateSelect.val(parseInt(dateArray[1]).toString());
                yearSelect.val(parseInt(dateArray[2]).toString());

            },{}
            ,evt).datepicker( "widget" ).css("z-index","9999");
            var syncDate = function(){
                //Depends on Locale
                var newDate = monthSelect.val()+'/'+dateSelect.val()+'/'+yearSelect.val();
                comp.datepicker("setDate", newDate);
            };
            syncDate();
            dateSelect.on("change", syncDate);
            monthSelect.on("change", syncDate);
            yearSelect.on("change", syncDate);
            return false;
        });
        });
```

Comment: yeah sure ...  i need some examples,

Comment: I tried editing renderEditor.template
am still working on it ...i hope your examples will help ..

Comment: thank you fol your help :)
i have figured it out.Just made some changes inside renderEditor.template